# Calculate the multiplication of an ArrayList

Tags: java

I'm so stuck of how to get the answer below, this question required to use the ArrayList and recursion as well. Code below is what I've got so far, and now I'm so stuck. I've done a lot of research but still not find the answer. If you can, you can explain and provide some answer, THANK YOU.

The elements of your array are: 1 2 3 4 5 6 -1

The multiplication of {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6} is 720.

Also, if the user enters the negative number, the ArrayList won't multiply that number. Please help.

```
public class Arraylist{
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("The elements of your array are: ");
        int num = scan.nextInt();
        ArrayList<Integer> element = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        while (true){
            element.add(scan.nextInt());

            }


        }

    }
```

Comment: "now I'm so stuck" - with which part are you stuck? You should start by properly reading the input, probably not in an infinite loop. Then you just iterate over the whole list and multiplicate the numbers. No idea why would you use recursion for that.

Comment: It seems simple. As Amongalen said, store the incoming values, create a variable into which you can store the intermediate multiplication values, and loop over the list. Each time a new values comes in, you multiply this with the updated multiplication value (use the multiplication compound assignment operator), ensuring that it isn't a negative value. Write out some pseudo code first, and then try to code it.

Answer (score 1):

**Considering negative value terminate loop**

```java
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.print("The elements of your array are: ");

ArrayList<Integer> element = new ArrayList<Integer>();
int ans = 1;
while (true){
    int num = scan.nextInt();
    if(num < 0)
        break;
    element.add(num);
    ans *= num;
}
System.out.println(ans);
```

Answer (score -1):

Define a recursive function to get the product.

```
public class Arraylist{
    public static int getProduct(ArrayList<Integer> elements, int index) {
        if(index == elements.size() ) return 1;
        else
            return (elements.get(index) > 0)? 
                    elements.get(index): 1 * 
                    getProduct(elements, i+1);

    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter number of elements:");
        int num = scan.nextInt(), prod = 1;
        ArrayList<Integer> elements = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        System.out.println("Enter " + num +  " elements:");

        for(int i = 0; i < num; i++) {
         elements.add(scan.nextInt());
        }
        prod = getProduct(elements);
         System.out.println("Product is: " + prod);
    }
```

Comment: Updated to use recursion

Comment: Updated to use recursion